# Problems with copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

Dont pay attention to the actual code, just read the question.
I have a function that takes 2 parameters of type Polynomial:

```
FiniteFieldElement(int l, Polynomial p, Polynomial irr)
{
    this->l = l;
    this->p = p;
    this->irr = irr;
}
```

My understanding is that Polynomial's copy constructor will be called when p and irr are being passed.

The copy constructor is working properly, as I can verify by a breakpoint at the end.

```
Polynomial(const Polynomial& p)
{
    degree = p.degree;
    modulo = p.modulo;
    if (polynomial != p.polynomial)
    {
        polynomial = new int[degree + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
        {
            polynomial[i] = p.polynomial[i];
        }
    }
}
```

But why am I getting wrong (uninitialized) values for the actual parameters p and irr. What could be coming in between the result of the copy constructor and the actual parameters? If I change the parameter to a reference parameter, it works fine. (Note: Polynomial has no destructor, if that helps).

EDIT: If I declare a polynomial using the copy constructor `Polynomial p1(p2)`, p1 gets initialized correctly. In the class FiniteFieldElement, I'm getting wrong Polynomial parameters. I'm completely stumped.

Comment: if `Polinomial` has no user defined destructor you are leaking the `polinomial` `int[]`

Comment: How are you determining that the parameters are uninitialised, just out of interest?

Comment: @Andrei Yes, I know. I just wanted to make clear that the destructor has nothing to do with this error.

Comment: @razbale breakpoint at this->l = l;

Comment: @JohnSums In the end, the skill you need to develop is called debugging. Use a debugger, step through the program and see when its behavior deviates from the expectations. Once you do this, the fix should be obvious. If it is not, edit the answer and someone will aid you.

Comment: @Andrei I am using a debugger. The reason I'm confused is I can't figure out what else could be running between a breakpoint at the end of the copy constructor and a breakpoint at the beginning of the function that's using the parameters. Not just for my code, but generally, what could come in between?

Comment: Does class `Polynomial` implement the Big Three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone it turns out the Eclipse CDT debugger was giving me wrong values. The same breakpoint in Visual studio (or just printing the values [see modulo below]) gives me the correct answers. Maybe I'm not using it correctly, but when you enter a watch expression in the debugger you expect to get the right value.

[image: Eclipse CDT bug]

Answer (score 3):

> My understanding is that Polynomial's copy constructor will be called when p and irr are being passed.

That only partially correct. A copy is possibly made since the `Polinomials` are passed by value (but copy elision could mean no copy is made at all), but inside `FiniteFieldElement(int l, Polynomial p, Polynomial irr)`, `Polynomial`'s copy assignment operator will be called, assuming `this->p` and `this->irr` are of type `Polynomial`. So your class' fields are the result of an assignment, not a copy.

So you should be looking at the implementation of your copy assignment operator.

Comment: I cant understand it. The copy constructor is fine. Then how he is getting undefined value at finite field element?

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT maybe the assignment operator is broken?

Comment: but when he passes as a reference, it works....at least that is what is said in the question...`If I change the parameter to a reference parameter, it works fine.` .... so the assignment operator is not broken.

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry, still not clear. His claim is `But why am I getting wrong (uninitialized) values for the actual parameters p and irr.`, i.e the actual parameters are not at all initiazed. If the copy constructor is fine, then parameters must have passed correctly na? - please clarify

Comment: It's not a problem with operator=. The actual parameter values received are uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Are you *actually* initializing the polynomial?
Doing `new int[degree_ + 1];` will not construct an *initialized* array, its values are garbage.

*Edit*: Unless there is another very good reason why you need a `int*` you are better off using a `std::vector` as your polynomial coefficients container. It will simplify object construction, destruction and assignment.

This works well (which means the problem is in the part of the code which you are not showing us: the class defintions and assignment operators)

```
class Polynomial
{
public:

    Polynomial();
    Polynomial( const Polynomial& p );
    template <int N> Polynomial(int (&Poly)[N] );

    Polynomial& operator=( const Polynomial& Rhs);

    void Print();

    ~Polynomial();
private:
    int* poly_;
    int degree_;
};

class FiniteFieldElement
{
public:
    FiniteFieldElement( Polynomial P );

    void Print();
private:
    Polynomial p_;
};
```

and the implementations:

```
Polynomial::Polynomial()
{
    degree_ = 0;
    poly_ = new int[degree_ + 1];

    poly_[0] = 1;
}

// excessive, you don't really need this
template <int N> Polynomial::Polynomial(int (&Poly)[N] )
{
    degree_ = N - 1;
    poly_ = new int[degree_ + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= degree_; i++)
    {
        poly_[i] = Poly[i];
    }
}

Polynomial& Polynomial::operator=( const Polynomial& Rhs)
{        
    if ( this != &Rhs )
    {
        degree_= Rhs.degree_;

        delete[] poly_;

        poly_ = new int[degree_ + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= degree_; i++)
        {
            poly_[i] = Rhs.poly_[i];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}


void Polynomial::Print()
{
    std::cout<< "Degree = " << degree_ << "\n Polynomial = ";
    for (int i = 0; i <= degree_; i++)
    {
        std::cout<< poly_[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
}

Polynomial::~Polynomial()
{
    delete[] poly_;
}

Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial& p)
{
    degree_ = p.degree_;
    poly_ = new int[degree_ + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= degree_; i++)
    {
        poly_[i] = p.poly_[i];
    }
}
```

and

```
FiniteFieldElement::FiniteFieldElement( Polynomial P )
{
    p_ = P;
}

void FiniteFieldElement::Print()
{
    p_.Print();
}
```

main is just:

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int myPoly[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    Polynomial foo(myPoly);

    FiniteFieldElement bar( foo );

    std::cout<< "Foo:\n";
    foo.Print();
    std::cout<< "Bar:\n";
    bar.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

If it works on your machine see how it differs from your implementation, both in code and in behavior.